# SwiftUI DatePicker day of week language

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

I adjusted the region of the DatePicker via the locale property, but the days of the week and the word time are still displayed in English. How can I change that or what did I do wrong?

```
DatePicker(selection: $aufgabenEigenschaften.aufgabenDatum) {
    Text("Fällig:")
        .foregroundColor(Color("eigenesColorSet"))
}
.environment(\.locale, Locale.init(identifier: "de_DE"))
.onTapGesture(perform: beschreibungsInhalt)
.padding()
```

[image: why?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple. The appropriate language is added under the project and the Localizations item.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you added in your Localizable file? For French I tried "sun" = "Lun" and "SUN" = "Lun" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to previous answer (and because I don't have the "reputation" to comment directly in Newcomer's answer), creating a blank Localizable.strings file for the language you need is enough to make it work.
You don't have to specify and translate.