# Using SwiftUI how can I force a DatePicker to use the 24 Hour date format rather than the locale the user has on their device

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, datepicker

I am trying to force my SwiftUI DatePicker to override the user's settings and only display a 24 hour time format within the picker itself.  This would be relevant in an aviation related app.  I have seen some old posts using UIDatePicker and overriding the locale, but that also didn't work for me.  The code I'm using with SwiftUI is below and this does not work on a physical device to force 24 hour time inside picker.  It does work on the Xcode simulator but not on actual device.

```
DatePicker("Start Time", selection: $startTime, displayedComponents: DatePickerComponents.hourAndMinute)
    .environment(\.locale, Locale.init(identifier: "da"))
```

When I run this on my device with region set to US, it still displays hours and minutes with am/pm inside the picker.   I have tried other locales that use only 24 hour time but it still displays am/pm within the picker itself.  Although it does change the selected time to 24 hours.  My issue is within the picker itself.

It seems there is nothing that can be done to override the users 24 hour time setting in Settings/General/Date & Time/24-Hour Time

I can implement a custom popover and wheel spinners to mimic this, but that runs into issues on an iPhone going fullScreen.  I'm sure there are other work arounds using custom logic, but I was wondering if there is anyway to force the native DatePicker not to use am/pm.

I am able to show 24 hour time on the Xcode simulator by changing locale but it doesn't work on a physical device.

Comment: Is your device set to am/pm or 24hr?

Comment: device set to am/pm.  I want this to display 24 hour time regardless what anyone's device is set to.l

Answer (score 3):

Simply change **en_DK** to **da** and **en_GB** to **en**. Working code is here. Tested in Swift Playgrounds and on real device iPhone 14 with iOS 16.5.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var identifier = "en"
    @State var startTime: Date = .now
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            DatePicker("Start Time", selection: $startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            Button("da", action: {
                self.identifier = "da"
            })
            Button("en", action: {
                self.identifier = "en"
            })
        }
        .padding()
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: identifier))
    }
}
```

Comment: It does work well in playground and on Xcode simulator, however this does not work on a physical device.  On my iPhone it still shows am/pm in the picker although the picked value is displayed in 24 hour format.  My issue is the picker values.  I don't want the am/pm

Comment: This is strange that it is not working on your device. I just tested the code above on real device and it is working fine. I tested the code on iPhone 14 with iOS 16.5. I have these settings on iPhone: General / Date & Time / 24-Hours Time: disabled. General / Language & Region / Preferred Languages / English. General / Language & Region / Region / United States. If you still have a problem, try to add appropriate language under the project and the Localizations item as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66777345/21994349

Comment: I have all of the exact settings as you.  My only language is English.  I don't have "da".  is that German?  I can try to add that in localizations but if you also only have English it doesn't explain the difference.  I'm running exactly the app sample you have.  The display does change from am/pm to 24 hour.  The values in the picker though retain the am/pm regardless of selection and that's my problem.

Comment: I added Danish (da) and it didn't make any difference.  Can you confirm that the actual values in your picker itself are not showing am/pm with the settings 24-Hours Time disabled?

Comment: You are right. Time in picker itself depends on device settings. When 24-Hours Time is disabled, the picker in app still shows am/pm even time in view is correctly in 24 hour format. Picker does not follow locale settings in application. I will try to find solution.